# could not deserialize eof Exception

Tags: hibernate, serialization

My application is using hsql as database. It was working fine till now. In the production I got the exception org.hibernate.SerializationException could not deserialize EOF exception. I couldn't get the complete stack trace because the exception is not caught properly in my code.

I also don't have the exact sequence of events that caused this exception. After I restarted the tomcat and hql the problem disappeared.

Sorry to be vague, but please I need some help with root cause analysis. What could have been the issue here?

```
validateSession();
        Session session = SessionFactory.getInstance(SessionContext.DISTRIBUTED).getSession();
        session.beginTransaction();
        List results;
        try {
            Criteria cri = session.createCriteria(Filter.class);
            cri.add(Restrictions.eq( "user", userVO.user() ));
            setLazyMode(cri);
            results = cri.list();
            session.getTransaction().commit();
        } finally {
            rollbackIfStillOpen(session);
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Dunno if it will help you but I had same issue and it appeared I had my @Id above the member instead of the getter...

I feel the hibernate exception messages are very very poor. I had to debug and create special test cases to pin down the problem. Would it have been that difficult for hibernate to state: I cannot find an Id. Is it annotated or mapped? Put your annotation on the getter instead of the member.

Which brings me to the fact I don't get why one time it has to be on the getter and the other time on the member... Why not put all on the member or the getter?? Both getter and member are linked to each other so why all this crap?